# Smooth convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $E\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a convex set, $\beta\geq 0$ be a given real number and $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be a convex and differentiable function satisfying:
$$f(y)\leq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^\top (y-x) +\frac{\beta}{2}\|x-y\|_2^2, \quad \forall x,y\in E.$$
Show that $\nabla f$ is $\beta$-Lipschitz, i.e.,
$$\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|_2\leq\beta\|x-y\|_2, \quad \forall x,y\in E.$$

Edit: I am interested in the case when $E$ can be any convex subset of $\mathbb R^d$. When $E=\mathbb R^d$, the claim can be proven as proposed by the answer below. However, in many convex optimisation textbooks, the claim is stated for general domains $E$ without proof.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Imho this is good (reference) question. I have seen the claim several times for general convex $E$, but only found proofs for $E=\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: If the smoothness condition holds for some $x,y\in E$, does the reverse $f(x) \leq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^\top(x-y) + \beta/2\lVert x-y\rVert_2^2$ also hold?

Comment: @bodil this is just the inequality with $x,y$ exchanged

Comment: Just to mention, Theorem 2.1.5 from "Lectures on Convex Optimization" by Nesterov suggests that the statement does not hold for a general $E$. Instead, we have the weaker additional conditions: $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^\top(x-y) \leq \beta\lVert x-y\rVert^2_2$, and $0\leq \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y) - f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\leq \alpha(1-\alpha)\frac{\beta}{2}\lVert x-y\rVert^2_2$ with $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be open, convex and assume that $f$ is convex, differentiable and satisfies your inequality.
It is easy to check that $\nabla f$ is continuous:

> Let $(x_n) \subset E$ be a sequence with $x_n \to x \in E$. Since $\nabla f(x_n)$ is bounded ($f$ is locally Lipschitz), we have $\nabla f(x_{n_k}) \to g$ for a subsequence. A standard argument shows that $g \in \partial f(x) = \{ \nabla f(x)\}$. A subsequence-subsequence argument shows that the entire sequence $(\nabla f(x_k))$ converges towards $\nabla f(x)$.

The answer by daw shows that we get
$$
\| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \| \le \beta \, \| y - x \|
$$
whenever $x,y \in E$ satisfy
$$
x + \frac1\beta \, \Big(\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\Big),\;
y + \frac1\beta \, \Big(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\Big) \in E.$$

Now, since $E$ is open, we can check that there is $\varepsilon_x > 0$,
such that all $y \in B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$ satisfy this condition.

Finally, let $x,y \in E$ be arbitrary. Since the segment $[x,y]$ is compact,
we can find finitely many $z_k \in [x,y]$, such that the corresponding balls cover $[x,y]$.
A repeated application of the triangle inequality shows the desired
$$
\| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \| \le \beta \, \| y - x \|.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your proof?

Comment: @bodil: Which part?

Comment: So, first showing that $x + \frac{1}{\beta}(\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))\in E$ and $y +\frac{1}{\beta}(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))\in E$ for all $x,y\in E$, or how this is satisfied locally, i.e. for an $\epsilon_x$ ball, and how is it useful in daw's proof. Then, I'm interested to see the last part with the triangle inequality in more detail.

Comment: Hi @gerw, thanks! Now, coming back to the general case, is it true that the gradient of a convex and differentiable function is continuous, even at boundary points? If so, the inequality $\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|\leq\beta \|x-y\|$, which can be proved for all $x,y$ in the interior of $E$, could be extended to any points of $E$ by continuity.

Comment: @TrivialPursuit: If $E$ is not open, how do you define "differentiable"? One easy case is the following: If $E \subset \Omega$, $\Omega$ is open and $f$ is the restriction of some convex, differentiable $g \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, you get the continuity of $\nabla f$.

Comment: @bodil: First point: You take $\delta < \varepsilon/2$ such that $\|\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\| \le \beta \, \varepsilon / 2$ for all $y \in B_\delta(x)$. Then, $\varepsilon_x = \delta$ does the job (triangle inequality). Second point: Take intermediate points $\xi_k = x + \lambda_k \, (y-x)$ for an increasing sequence $(\lambda_k) \subset [0,1]$ with $\xi_0 = x$, $\xi_m = y$ and such that $\xi_j, \xi_{j-1}$ belong to a ball on which the Lipschitz inequality holds. Then apply the triangle inequality again.

Comment: @gerw: If $E$ is convex but not open, then at each $x\in E$, say that a function $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x\in E$ if there exists $g\in\mathbb R^d$ such that for all $u\in E-x$, $f(x+u)-f(x)-g^\top u=\|u\|\varepsilon(u)$, where $\varepsilon$ is a function that satisfies $\varepsilon(u)\to 0$ as $u\to 0$. The only such vector $g$ that is parallel to $E$ (i.e. that is in the linear space spanned by $E-x$) is the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y,z\in \mathbb R^d$. Then by the smoothness condition
$$
f(x+z) \le f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tz + \frac\beta2 \|z\|_2^2
$$
and by convexity
$$
\nabla f(y)^T (x+z-y) \le f(x+z)-f(y).
$$
Adding both inequalities gives
$$
(\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))^Tz - \frac\beta2 \|z\|_2^2 \le f(x) - f(y) -\nabla f(y)^T(x-y).
$$
The left-hand side is maximal for $z= \frac1{\beta}(\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))$, which gives
$$
\frac1{2\beta} \|\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\|_2^2 \le f(x) - f(y) -\nabla f(y)^T(x-y).
$$
The inequality is true if we exchange $x$ and $y$. Adding the resulting both inequalities yields to
$$
\frac1{\beta} \|\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\|_2^2 \le (\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y).
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you. However, this proof only works when $E=\mathbb R^d$, whereas I am interested in the case of a general domain.